# create sharepoint 2010 internet site (.com)

Tags: internet-sites

I want to create sharepoint internet (.com) site. Can anyone please help me with steps and configuration requires to be created the same. How to create web application and all.

Comment: If you are planning to make it publicly accessible, you need to have the correct licensing. The question is unclear on this. It is likely cheaper to get 2013 which includes public licensing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps.

- You need a DNS entry for (internet.com), which is accessible on the internet.
- You need to login with Farm admin account on Central Admin
- [Now create the Web Application and Root level Site collection.](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1014)
- [Now update the AAM settings according to your requirement.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/configure-an-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)